# lxc containers process limit shared

Tags: containers, lxc

I have used lxc-create to build two containers, and use rlimit to limit number of process that the user can run.

```
rlim.rlim_cur=15;
rlim.rlim_max=15;
ret=setrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, &rlim);
```

after the setrlimit I will run another program, using execv().

when I run this setrlimit and fork 20 child process, it normally reached the limit.

At this time, I can't run any command on another container. When the fork program is finished,
another container works again.
I think two containers share the same source. Is it correct? How can I solve it?